# Format home video for wtv

Tags: windows-media-center

I've never done anything like this before, but I was wondering whether it is possible to take pre-recorded video, say in wmv format, and convert to wtv, place them in a Windows Media Center folder, and have it display in WMC when recorded TV is selected. My goal is to have friends record a birthday greeting for my roommate and have him see it when he tries to watch the evening news.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably much too late for your project, but from my research into the WTV format, [VideoReDo](http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm) gives you the ability to edit and create WTV files.  I have not used the program itself as it does more than I need, but might suit your needs.

FYI - it is NOT free, but there is a free trial that might let you do it.